# how to access owl file inside jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to access owl file using jsp.I've successfully load the owl file and quering that using SPARQL.But still I couldn't success with JSP.

I'm always getting error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager
"

help me!

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAR file should be placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the webapplication, not in `/WEB-INF/classes`.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, but talking about this problem in JSP context doesn't sound good. You should be using a real Java class for this task, e.g. a `HttpServlet`. JSP is a view technology.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is to examine the JAR files deployed to the webapp's `WEB-INF/classes` dir.  One of them should contain the `com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager` class.  If you cannot find the class, then you are missing a JAR file.

Comment: I have created reference for JAR files of jena and then added to the build path.I can import that libries(com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager)in my classes and jsp too.But the thing is still I'm getting same error.
Could you please tell me that how should I deploy JAR files to webapp's WEB-INF/classes.
Thank for your reply!